# UINavigationController on Pageview Template

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I have created an app using the pageview template. I have added a `UINavigationBar` to the data controller as it does not appear when I add it to the root controller. The navigation does display but it scrolls when I scroll the pageview. Can someone tell me how to keep the navigation bar static please.

Answer (score 1):

First you should add a `UINavigationController` and set it as a initial view controller. After that you need to set `UINavigationController`'s root view as your `RootViewController`.